# want to prove exponential identity with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove that $e^{x+y}=e^x*e^y$, where x and y are complex numbers. I only want to use that evey complex number is on the form $z=a+bi$, where $i^2=-1$.
And if z is a complex number we have $e^z=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

However I seem to get stuck, here is my attempt:

$x=a+bi$

$y=c+di$

$e^{x+y}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a+bi*c+di)^n}{n!}$. **I am not sure if we can use the binomial theorem on the part inside the summation, because we have $i$ there?, can we?**
If we can, I get

$=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty[\Sigma_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(a+bi)^k*(c+di)^{n-k}*\frac{1}{n!}]$. My problem is that I am not able to sepearte the n and the k, if I was able to show that this was equal to:

$\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(a+bi)^n}{n!}*\Sigma_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(c+di)^k}{k!}$ then I would have provedwhat I wanted, is there a way to get here?

Comment: Do you know why the binomial theorem is true? Go back and review, and see if there would be any issues for complex numbers for yourself. (In fact, it holds whenever multiplication is associative and commutative, which is pretty general.)

Comment: The binomial theorem is valid (you can prove this too). You can get rid of n factorial since you divided by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{u}e^{v}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{r}}{r!}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{v^{s}}{s!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r+s=n}\frac{u^{r}v^{s}}{r!s!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(u+v\right)^{n}}{n!}=e^{u+v}$$

---

**edit**

In general $$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_{r}\times\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}b_{s}=a_{0}b_{0}+\left(a_{0}b_{1}+a_{1}b_{0}\right)+\left(a_{0}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{0}\right)+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}$$
where $$c_{n}=a_{0}b_{n}+\cdots+a_{n}b_{0}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}$$

Another way to notate $c_{n}$ is $$c_{n}=\sum_{r+s=n}a_{r}b_{s}$$
where $r$ and $s$ stand for nonnegative integers.

Comment: I almost understand what you do, but I have a problem with your second equality. I went backwards from what you did, and I am stuck, could you please explain your second inequality? I have: $e^{x+y}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\Sigma_{s=0}^n\frac{x^s*y^{n-s}}{n!}*\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}=\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\Sigma_{s=0}^n\frac{x^s*y^{n-s} }{s!(n-s)!}$, then I substitute n-s with r, to get $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty\Sigma_{s+r=n}\frac{x^s*y^r}{s!*r!}$ How do I then get $\Sigma_{s=0}^\infty\frac{x^s}{s!}*\Sigma_{r=0}^\infty\frac{y^r}{r!}$

Comment: After my third equality it is supposed to be divided by s!(n-s)!(not multiplied), but it doesn't seem to work when I type it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the exponential series is absolutely convergent on $\Bbb C$ so we can use the Cauchy product of the series:

$$e^xe^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}\\=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}=e^{x+y}$$

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in writing the real and imaginary parts of the complex numbers $x$ and $y$.

According to your formula for $e^{x+y}$, what is the coefficient of $x^ry^s$ for given $r,s\ge0$?

Answer (score 0):

For z and w being complex,  $$
$$ $e^{z}*e^{w}$=$e^{(x+iy)}*e^{(a+ib)}$=$(e^{x}*e^{iy})*(e^{a}*e^{ib})$=$(e^{x}*e^{a})*(e^{iy}*e^{ib})=e^{(x+a)}*e^{i(b+y)}=e^{(x+a)+i(y+b)}=e^{z+w}$. I dont understand why I have to make my life complicated with the Taylor series Expansion for $e^{z}.$

Comment: How to prove $e^{x}\times e^{a}=e^{x+a}$ for $x,a\in\mathbb{R}$? This without
Taylor expansion.

Comment: @drhab Is that really a problem?, can't you assume in that case that you allready know it holds for real numbers? Isn't the bigger problem that he uses $e^{x+iy}=e^x*e^{iy}$, but we haven't proved it for complex numbers yet?

Comment: You have a point there. If it is not proved for complex numbers yet, then indeed you have no right to say that $e^{x+yi}=e^{x}\times e^{yi}$. If you are proving 'things' about $e^z$ then you are somehow obliged to go to its definition. Then you come out by Taylor expansion. Also in the real case.